# backpressure support in grizzly websocket

Tags: websocket, java-11, grizzly, java-websocket

Does the grizzly web socket library support flow control/back pressure ?

If so, which version of grizzly web socket library supports the back pressure ? please share the library /documentation links.

Does Java 11 Websocket api support backpressure or any other open source library supports  ?

Pointers to relevant link will be helpful.

Thanks,
Manpreet